# How to fix this workflow issue "there is no POM in this directory" in GitHub Actions? (Applying the concept of calling reusable workflows)

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I was trying apply the concept of calling reusable workflows. I have a workflow for automated tests in repo1, and an actions workflow in repo2. The goal is to call on workflow/s from another repository and test execution/s should be successful.

However, I have encountered an error that says "The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\a\github-actions-course-test\github-actions-course-test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]"

Please see images/details below. How do we solve this kind of issue/s? Sorry I'm new to github actions since this will be used in my project for the CI/CD. I may have missed something or probably this is not the right way of reusing workflows. I'm open for suggestions and ideas that might resolve this issue. Thank you so much!!

[image]

[image]

error:

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (D:\a\github-actions-course-test\github-actions-course-test). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

**repo 1 workflow**

```
name: test_execution

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 9,12,15,18,20,0,3,6 * 1-12 1-5"
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  workflow_call:
    secrets:
      SOME_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'

      - name: Build with Maven and Test execution of Google Smoke Test
        run: mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile="google.xml"
```

**repo 2 workflow**

```
name: Actions Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  run-github-actions:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps: 
      - name: List Files
        run: |
          ls  
          echo $GITHUB_SHA
          echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY
          echo $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
          echo "${{ github.token }}"
          echo "for testing purposes"
  automation-test:
    needs: ["run-github-actions"]
    uses: mirandaxyrus13/testautomationframework/.github/workflows/test_execution.yml@master
    secrets:
      SOME_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SOME_SECRET }}
```

Comment: Could you share your project architecture in the question, and specifically where your pom.xml file is located? It seems the folder where you're executing the `mvn` command in your workflow doesn't contain a pom.xml file

Comment: @GuiFalourd  I'm not sure on this part -> "Could you share your project architecture in the question". But the pom.xml file is located in repo2, in a different repo. What is your email address? Could we have a quick discussion on this?

Comment: In that case, the mvn command you used in your repo1 workflow should instead appear in the repo2 workflow, shouldn't it?